# Run batch silently by hotkey (permissions issue?)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, autohotkey, volume, remote-execution

I am trying to control Spotify volume from inside a game without switching windows. To do this I did the following:

A. Found nircmd.exe from NirSoft that can control individual program volumes in Windows
B. Wrote a batch to execute the command
C. Wrote this .vbs script to hook into the batch silently:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" )
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "Spotify App Volume Up.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

^
Using this .vbs snippet to accomplish silent run is really popular. **This works when I click the .vbs myself. The problem I have is I need a way to execute this from another program.** When I try to execute from any hotkey program or something like AutoHotKey it gives me this error:

*ActiveX Component cannot create object 'WScript.Shell' Code: 800a01ad*

I tried setting security of all involved files to everyone, full control. It did not help. It seems to me that Windows is trying to protect me by preventing scripts from initializing by other programs. Any suggestions? Otherwise does someone know how to execute this silently with another method?

**EDIT:**

AutoHotKey's run command will do this:
`run "mybat.bat",, Hide`
However, does anyone know how to get around this behavior with .vbs? I am curious.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `how to get around this behavior with .vbs`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all your scripts, vbscript and your batch file can potentially be written natively in Ahk, but here's how I'd launch your vb script.

```
x:: ; press x
sc := ComObjCreate("ScriptControl")

sc.Language := "VBScript"

script =
(
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" )
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "Spotify App Volume Up.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing 
)

sc.ExecuteStatement(script)

return
```